# Collapsing, summing up and renaming columns in a table in R

Tags: r

I have a table with a number of columns (simple example):

```
a b c d  
1 1 2 2  
2 3 4 3
```

I want to collapse the last columns into one and add the contents to produce something like this:

```
a b other  
1 1     4   
2 3     7
```

I can manage to find ways of adding the last columns and renaming them, but I can't append them to the table again without changing the data format, and I need them to be a table because I have to create a graph.

Comment: You've tagged this "datatables". Are you referring to the "data.table" package? Or are you using this as synonymous with "data.frame"?

Comment: Actually there is a difference between a data.frame and a data table in R. I think the correct tag should be "datatable" and not "DataTables" which I think is a plug-in for another programming language.

Comment: Yes, I know that. And the correct tag for a "data.table" object using the "data.table" package is [tag:data.table].

Comment: I was actually just using the data table functionality in {base} :)

Comment: There is no "data.table" in base. At any rate, did Sven's answer not address what you were looking for?

Comment: There is some basic data table functionality. I have never installed the data.table package, and it still works. And yes, the answer below worked. Somebody just started changing the tags of this post a few days ago, but it may not have been you since your initial comment is from 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A data frame:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "a b c d
1 1 2 2
2 3 4 3", header = TRUE)
```

You can calculate the sums with `rowSums`:

```
cbind(dat[1:2], other = rowSums(dat[3:4]))

#   a b other
# 1 1 1     4
# 2 2 3     7
```

Comment: doesn't `cbind` automatically coerce to `matrix`?

Comment: @Manetheran This code returns a data frame if data frames are used as arguments.